# AppendChild Is Not working with textcontent (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am Creating a Div with createElement then creating strong tag inside this div with createElement and assing it a text and append it inside firstDiv(which i previously created), and then i assigning content to main Div (previously created div). But It is showing only the text content , not showing me the strong tag which i created .

please help me where i am wrong. Here is the

Attached Image:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code in the post, and as a code block, not an image.

Comment: Reading the image, what do you think setting `textContent` would do?

Comment: @Rajat - edit your questing and paste the code into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textContent` replaces all the content in the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nmL7v5b/6/

You have to something like this

```js
var infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
infoDiv.setAttribute("class", "text-block");
var bio = document.createElement("strong");
bio.textContent = "Bio";
infoDiv.appendChild(bio);
var spanElem = document.createElement("div");
spanElem.textContent = "Full";
infoDiv.appendChild(spanElem)


document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(infoDiv)
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Or if you don't want to use `span` tag you can use `innerHTML` also like

http://jsfiddle.net/2nmL7v5b/11/

```js
var infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
infoDiv.setAttribute("class", "text-block");
var bio = document.createElement("strong");
bio.textContent = "Bio";
infoDiv.appendChild(bio);

infoDiv.innerHTML += "Full";

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(infoDiv)
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your need, you should use "createTextNode" instead of "textContent" in main div.

```
var infoDiv21 = document.createElement('div');
infoDiv21.setAttribute('class', 'text-block-19');
var bio = document.createElement('strong');
bio.textContent = "Bio";
infoDiv21.appendChild(bio);
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Rajat Full Bio"); // Create a text node
infoDiv21.appendChild(textnode);
```

(Advice : Please go through 'createTextNode' in detail before use.)